# Can I have public static fields in service bean?

Tags: java, spring, oop

I'm a bit sceptic of this code, since it kind of violates YAGNI. I need some public static fields for my service class, but usually it's a bad design when you have those in your service bean, so I created an interface for that service, but I'm not sure it's the right choice. Should I have those fields in service class?

```java
public interface IYouTubeServiceBuild {
    /**
     * Define a global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    /**
     * Define a global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    /**
     * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
     * contains the developer's API key.
     */
    public static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";
}
```

```java
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class YouTubeServiceBuild implements IYouTubeServiceBuild {
    @Getter
    private Properties properties;

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    @Getter
    private YouTube youtube;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        properties = new Properties();
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, request -> {
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-search-demo").build();
        //etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Above service class is then used in other service as follows:

```java
@Service
public class YouTubeApiService {
    @Autowired
    private YouTubeServiceBuild serviceBuild;

    public List<SearchResult> searchYouTube(String searchQuery) {
        List<SearchResult> searchResults =
                executeSearch(searchQuery, serviceBuild.getProperties(), serviceBuild.getYoutube());
        //etc...
    }
```

Comment: Your initial statement is wrong. You **don’t** need constant fields in your service bean. You need to create beans from those shared resources and wire them into where they are required. This is **whole point** of using a DI framework - so build software using the IoC pattern. Moreover, even if you did need these constant fields - you _definitely_ don’t need to reinvent the constant interface anti-pattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Okay, I removed interface, and now have two service beans dealing with YouTube api, one is singleton loaded on startup, the other is called when user is searching something. Both these classes need some constants, one during the start of the application, another when user is searching something. I declared all those constants in a separate class (*Constants.java). Is this ok? Now these services call directly this constants class, which doesn't feel right.

Comment: @BoristheSpider (reply to 2nd comment) Thank you for honest advice, really :) I don't have a lot of experience with Spring, have read half of Spring in Action 5, build some CRUD projects, (and before going into the second half [webflux, reactive programming, etc.]) currently focused on really understanding how to use what I know already about spring(-boot) correctly, not just write a code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is whether its possible to set public static fields in Spring managed bean - then yes, its possible, although I completely agree with you that its a bad design.

Leaving alone spring, putting constants in the interface so that the implementations of the interface will be able to access them is considered a code smell because all the implementations (assuming there are many) now can behave differently because some constant changes, or even worse - won't compile anymore if the constant is removed (what if not all the implementations are in the project).

Much better approach is creating a class of constants:

```
 public class YouTubeConstants {
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    ...
 }
```

In the class that needs an access to these constants you can use `YouTubeConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT` (or even shorted with static imports).

Now as for the presented design, let me propose an alternative:

The class `YouTubeApiService` basically needs an access to `YouTube` object only, it needs it to perform queries. No need for `YouTubeServiceBuild` intermediate object, no need for connection properties), IMHO it only complicates the code.

You can do something like this:

```
 @Service
 public class YouTubeApiService {
    @Autowired
    private YouTube youtube;

     public List<SearchResult> searchYouTube(String searchQuery) {
         List<SearchResult> searchResults =
            executeSearch(searchQuery,youtube);
         //etc...
     }
 }
```

Looks much better, doesn't it?

Now in order to create a youtube object, you need some code that goes a little bit beyond the regular "new". You can use a Configuration for this:

```
 import static YoutubeConstants.*;
 @Configuration
 public class YouTubeConfig {

    @Bean
    public YouTube youtube() {
      return new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, request -> {
         }).setApplicationName("youtube-search-demo").build();
    }
 }
```

In this implementation there is no need in a `YouTubeBuilder` at all

One more things to consider: 
It seems that you're trying to load some properties by yourself, notice, spring can to it alone.

I haven't seen any real usage of these properties in the code presented in the question, so I can't provide the working example, but please make sure you understand how to load properties in spring, you might inject the already-loaded properties into the `youtube` method in the configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a perfect solution. Is it ok that YouTube config directly communicate to YouTubeConstants? Can I probably add those constants to YouTubeConfig and remove YouTubeConstants? And is it ok that I define youTubeApiKeyProperty in application.properties? I need this apiKey in searchExecute() method.

Comment: Both ways are ok IMO

Comment: Get rid of `YoutubeConstants`. Declare those "constants" as beans. Autowire them. There should not be `public static` anywhere in a Spring Application unless it's followed by `class`.